# I am getting the following error when trying to run the react-native-digital-ink package

Tags: react-native, package, runtime-error

I am getting the following error when trying to run the react-native-digital-ink package

Is there any way to solve this error?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should install the component with `pod install` in ios folder. that way, react native will be able to use it in native

Comment: I have installed pod.

Answer (score 1):

After installing native modules (`pod install`) do not forget to rebuild the application

`npx react-native run-ios`

Comment: Yes I have done the following steps then also I am getting the following error is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Package is broken

Comment: The package works fine in android I am getting the following error in ios.

Comment: I also try to use this package. Something wrong with linking library